# Remove Symlink to home directory

Tags: symlink

How is a symlink removed from a home directory. I accidentally created a symlink for my home directory, but am worried that deletion will have unintended consequences on my real home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you jave just created a symlink you can simply `rm` it. Without the `-r` and `-f` it will not delete directories:

```
[me@localhost test]$ ln -s ~ alink
[me@localhost test]$ ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 11 Sep 15 02:54 alink -> /home/me
[me@localhost test]$ rm alink
[me@localhost test]$ ls -l
total 0
[me@localhost test]$ rm ~
rm: cannot remove '/home/me': Is a directory
```

If you have created a link/file/directory called `~` then you can run `rm -- '~'` to remove it, if it is a directory `rm -rf -- '~'`.

`--` Tells rm that any following arguments are not to be interpreted but are all filenames, the single quotes `'~'` tell bash to not interpret and expand the `~`.

However this is very risky to do. A safer way is to move the file first. That way if you mess up you can just move it back. This can be done the same way with `mv -- '~' newloaction` then `rm newlocation` once you are happy your home is still intact.

```
[me@localhost test]$ ln -s ~ -- '~'
[me@localhost test]$ ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me   11 Sep 15 02:51 '~' -> /home/me
[me@localhost test]$ rm -- '~'
[me@localhost test]$ ls -l
total 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing a symbolic link has no effect on the link-target (but you might need a link for *itself*, e.g., if that link is from a *preferred* location to a place where your home directory was *moved*).